# Not able to select anything in Contao backend without being kicked out

Tags: php, contao

I am trying to setup a Contao CMS instance on my webserver. I was able to install it. I can login to the backend but whenever I try to select something in the leftside navigation, I am kicked out of the backend and have to login again.

What could be the problem here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? Also check proper cookies domain in the installation.

Comment: Where can this be defined? Cookies in the browser are enabled, but I cannot set it in the backend due to the problem mentioned above.

Comment: You should download the Contao instance and deploy and test it locally first to confirm if the problem really is with Contao and not your webserver.